# Xamarin Forms [Android] Silent Push while App in Background => Freeze

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have a App that i now wanted to expand with Silent Push Functionality for a customers Feature Request.
But now i encounter a rather strange behaviour(app freeze)

- The Used Xamarin.Forms Version is 4.8.0.1451 (Updates did not solve the problem)
- The Problem is Android Only related
- Normal Notifications work as expected and dont produce any error

---

Here the quick Behaviour:

- Receiving Silent Pushes works if the app is in Foreground (Multible times no limit)
- Bringing the App to the Background and back to Foreground works also flawles

---

Do i Receive a Silent Push while the App is in Background or the Device is Locked and i bring back the App to Foreground/Unlock the device the app seems frozen (unresponsive and App.OnResume does not get executed)
(Also to note: i can only receive 1 silent push when the app is in Background/Device is locked)

- For now i dont do anything on receiving the Silen push (to isolate this error)
- Debug output aswell as LogCat does not provide any info what so ever.
- i could not track any managed code that does execute and not return properly from some method calls
- i can reproduce this problem on android 11(Pixel3) and android 9(Blackview A60)

I hope someone here has an idea what this problem could be.

It more informations or details are needed, i happily provide

Answer (score 0):

In Android, starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), an Android application no longer have the ability to run freely in the background.

> When in the foreground, an app can start and run services without
> restriction. When an application moves into the background, Android
> will grant the app a certain amount of time to start and use services.
> Once that time has elapsed, the app can no longer start any services
> and any services that were started will be terminated. At this point
> it is not possible for the app to perform any work.

For more details about this, you can refer to [Background Execution Limits in Android 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80).

Comment: Sorry, i dont see where i mentioned a background service etc. Also where does this restriction, freeze the app in the background(the app remains frozen if i get it back to the front).

Comment: I mean that an Android application no longer have the ability to run freely in the background for a long time for the sake of system efficiency.  For more , check: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.

Comment: As stated in my initial post, i dont do anything for now to isolate this error. Anyway. i could solve this problem today and will provide the solution required later this week when i have a few minutes to spare.

Comment: Congrats,and thanks for your willing to sharing your solution. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @Ranndom Could you share an example of how you managed to solve this problem? Thansk in advance

Comment: @OscarMoncayo on hindsight it was a problem in a private libarary were using, that caused that freeze. it was just an exception that was caught, NOT logged and did lead to a thread deadlock. Sorry if you hoped my solution could help you with a similar problem.